# IIS6.0 Subauthentication to AD

Tags: active-directory, iis-6, authentication

So I have Windows 2003 with IIS6 Hosting an MVC web app that requires domain authentication. Any Good Ideas on how to do this. The errors I get is 400, 401 or service unavailable.
I have followed the guides on setting up MVC Isapi however in doing wireshark monitoring I see that the domain responds but the local server denies the authentication. I have gone by this technet article. http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1f708fa2-54ab-4da0-a5eb-d6a6c453c939.mspx?mfr=true 
However this does not work. Help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try as following:

> > Go to Properties of your website.
> >     Go to Directory Security 
> >     Enable anonymours User and there you will be able to enter Domain User and Password.

Then,

Go to command prompt and register IIS as below, this is required for Service Unavailable Error

> > cd \ ( It will take you to C:)
> >     cd \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\V2.0.50727

aspnet_regiis -e
aspnet_regiis -i
reset iis.

Comment: This line crashes or will not run. aspnet_regiis -e aspnet_regiis -i reset iis

Comment: Trying this. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326020